# Grub displays on-screen unable to get into bios

Tags: archlinux, grub2

I installed GRUB and it only shows GRUB on the screen, I am unable to type anything. I am unable to get back into my bios to boot from usb.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you see is GRUB printed on the screen, something is wrong with your grub installation.
You can follow these steps to correct:

1. Boot the PC from a [livecd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) USB or CDROM (can be Ubuntu, for example)
2. Reinstall grub by typing `grub-install /dev/<target block device>`
3. Reboot and test

If you still have issues after these steps post what you're getting

Comment: I am unable to get into the bios, so I am unable to boot to a live cd or usb

Comment: If you're not able to load the bios then grub isn't the issue. Try disconnecting the HD, removing the motherboard battery and see if you can get to the bios then. Anyhow, this is off topic for stack overflow